# Make div positioned fix inside bootstrap carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want make div positioned fixed inside bootstrap carousel so content down the div can go under it. But nothing seems to work. Here is the link to my  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpqb89sv/1/).

I want to make`div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 fixed-div"` fixed so that it wouldn't go outside screen.

Anyone can help? I really appreciate it .
Here is the link to my  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bpqb89sv/1/).

Comment: It is somewhat unclear what you are trying to achieve. What do you mean by "under", z-axis or y-axis? Just to bring out one possibility, the 'overflow' property may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle and your question are hard to understand. But if you want something fixed inside your slider you should try adding  `position:relative;` to your`div class="item"`.
Then add the `position:fixed` to the child div inside that.

Like this,

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 fixed-div">content</div>
```

Css

```
  .item{position:relative}
   .fixed-div{position:fixed}
```

But fixing something inside a slider does not look good. If you want something to appear in every slide you should put that div inside every `div class="item"`. That is easy.

Answer (score 0):

Not much clear form your fiddle regarding which div you are trying to get fixed position. But the solution can be like this.

```
<div class="parent-div">  <!--/ Could be your slider wrapper or a single slide wrapper -->
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 fixed-div">your fixed content</div>
</div>
```

And style this way

```
.parent-div{position:relative;} /*This won't let your fixed-div to go outside of this*/
.parent-div .fixed-div{position:fixed;} /*And you can positon by top,bottom,left,right property*/
```